# Check for the font color of the powerpoint table when a certain style is selected

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have some tables with different table styling, option that you can select on the table design. I need to get the font color of each element of the table. For that I am using the following peace of code:

```
For i = 1 To rowNum
    For j = 1 To colNum
         table.table.Rows(i + 1).Cells(j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.font.color.RGB = sh.table.Rows(i + 1).Cells(j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.font.color.RGB
    Next j
Next i
```

The problem is that the value that I am getting is -2147483648 that is totally wrong so when I fire the code above the "table" table's font color is set to 0 witch is not its real value. How can I get the real font color value from the "sh" table?